# Videos as textures are pitch black

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

I'm using Blender 2,78, Blender render, and trying to upload video as a texture through [`Images as Planes`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/images_as_planes.html)

When I do that, the plane is pitch black with no texture, even if UV map is set as well as material and texture in *properties* tag. Movie is wmv. file and it sometimes plays 2 frames, sometimes not even that. The result is always black plane with no texture, even if texture is set.

Comment: Even if there are textures they need to be lit (af). Try setting your material to **shadeless** or increasing its **emit** value.

Comment: Just a guess, but the wmv format can be a pain in many applications. Can you try to convert the video into h264/mp4 and have another go at it?

Comment: It turns out that wmv is really a bad idea. For anyone struggling with this issue - I used mp4 and set it to shadeless and it's perfect. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and adding a *Sun* light source, with 0 *Specular*, did lit the video texture.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)